# positioning images within Group

Tags: lua, coronasdk

How do I position individual images within a image group?

I'm currently using the following code:

```
--category 1
local light1 = display.newImage("Images/Category 1/pistol1.png")
local light2 = display.newImage("Images/Category 1/machinePistol1.png")

--category 1 image group
local lightGroup = display.newGroup()
lightGroup.x, lightGroup.y = 100, 150
lightGroup:insert( light1 )
lightGroup:insert( light2 )
lightGroup.isVisible = false
```

But it places both the images on top of each other.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You still have to set the X, Y on each of the images you are creating.

```
 light1.x = 100
 light1.y = 100
 light2.x = 200
 light2.y = 100
```

Comment: Oooh, I see! Wasnt aware that was still possible. Thanks!